# How to use Mathematica to do a complex integrate with poles in real axis?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I want to use *Mathematica* to compute the following complex integral:

```
Integrate[Exp[I z ] 1/z, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

*Mathematica* reports that it does not converge on `{-Infinity, Infinity}`.

But, from the textbook, we know, the result is `I Pi`.

Of course, if I use `NIntegrate`, then, *Mathematica* will give `0. + 3.14 I`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
Integrate[Exp[I z] 1/z, {z, -Infinity, Infinity},PrincipalValue -> True]
(*I π*)
```

Answer (score 9):

One can also consider using the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). The residue is readily obtained by

```
Residue[Exp[I z] 1/z, {z, 0}]
```

returning `1`, which means that the integral is $ \mathrm i \pi $.

Comment: This for me is the most satisfactory solution.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure about your integral's behavior you can try

```
Integrate[Exp[I z] 1/z, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]
(* I π *)
```